# Sublime text change text color

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am currently trying to extract information (manually) from a text file. The text file has a decent format (parsable), but it contains something like 'random chars'. These random chars are not completely random, by running an algorithm on them I am able to collect information. I am giving each char a positive integer.

The question is whether or not I can write a sublime text 3 plugin that will help me see those chars.

I would like to change the colour of those chars.

Note: there can be a char in the same string with 2 colours. The colour depends on of the position.

Can such a plugin be written for sublime text 3? If not what can I use instead? The algorithm that gives each char a score is written in python.

Comment: WHy don't you try?

Comment: I am trying but I dont know the sublime api very well. I cannot fint any method that sets the foreground color

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the color of a [`Region`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html#sublime.Region) of text, you'll need to have a customized [scope selector](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#scopes) in your color scheme. Then, once you've chosen the text you want to highlight and converted it to a Region, you can use the `add_regions()` method of [`sublime.View`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html#sublime.View) (accessible within your [`sublime_plugin.TextCommand`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.TextCommand) subclass as `self.view`) to add the regions to the view and assign a scope to them. The regions should then be highlighted according to your color scheme.

Comment: the scope parameter in `add_regions` is there to retrieve a color for highlight and gutter mark. That scope will not get applied to the respective region. Hence text color remains unchanged. The API doc reads "The scope is used to source a color to draw the regions in". Could you clarify MattDMo?

Comment: I found out if you do not pass flag parameters to the method it indeed colors the scope. With flag parameters, it is not working. Your answer should reflect this, MattDMo!

Comment: This method seems to colour the background, not the foreground, on Sublime  build 3211, even when omitting the flags from the `add_regions` call.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have any experience working with the Sublime API directly, I've had plugins that highlight things in my files with a rectangle/outline.  It appears from the [api reference](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) that Regions are used to handle this.  There is an add_regions() function that you may want to look into.  The reference lists Packages/Default/mark.py as an example plugin that uses this function.

As for changing foreground specifically, the last post [in this thread](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/add-regions-swaps-background-and-foreground/3587/5) suggests that it is not possible.

Comment: Your forum link is from January 2013, and refers to Sublime Text 2. The API has been significantly improved since then (there is also a semi-official bug tracker, and most of the default packages have been open-sourced), and this is now possible - see my answer for how.

Comment: @MattDMo Good info!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in **CudaText** app, with Python API. API has `on_change_slow` event to run your code. And your code must find text x/y position, then call `ed.attr()` to highlight substring at x/y with any color. It's simple.